# Syntax of nested sql aggregate functions

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL on [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-sql-aggregate-functions/lessons/aggregate-functions/exercises/)

There's an example of nested aggregate function:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(price), 2)
FROM fake_apps;
```

`ROUND()` requires a number as first parameter, how can `AVG(price)` be plugged in here? What's the datatype of it?

If I change the code to:

```
SELECT ROUND(SELECT AVG(price)
             FROM fake_apps, 2)
FROM fake_apps;
```

The code throws a syntax error.

Comment: Your first query should work, so what is the problem?

Comment: No worreis mate it's been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code gives a syntax error because [ROUND](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) is a scalar function. It expects exactly one value as the first parameter.

```
SELECT ROUND(SELECT AVG(price)
             FROM fake_apps, 2)
FROM fake_apps;
```

SELECT AVG(price) FROM fake_apps returns a set of rows.

On the other hand, [AVG](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32693.html) is an aggregate function. It operates on a set of rows. The return type is numeric.

Comment: There is no point in writing the query you wrote.  The OP can just run the subquery directly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Re your comment on this answer, its code is just repeated from the question, which gives good & bad queries & asks why they do & don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs nested select query, at least as per your requirement example you have provided. This may be resolved with following query also.

```
SELECT ROUND(  AVG (price), 2 ) FROM fake_apps
```

DataType should be decimal or numeric with precision (for e.g. numeric (18,3) )
Let me know if I interpreted as wrong question and correct me, so I can try another way.

Comment: Thanks but I've already understood based on @chandra's answer, have a nice day!